# How to write for loop to count frequency in specific row

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to count frequencies of specific rows by age groups, the steps are:
1. the data frame of "pud", when the column of "icd3" meet the following conditions 
2. Select the qualified rows and count the frequencies.

The codes are as follows:

```
u2<-which(pud$icd3>="A00"&pud$icd3<="A99"|
              pud$icd3>="B00"&pud$icd3<="B94"|
              pud$icd3=="B99")
u3<-which(pud$icd3>="A00"&pud$icd3<="A99"|
            pud$icd3>="B00"&pud$icd3<="B49"|
            pud$icd3>="B90"&pud$icd3<="B94"|
            pud$icd3=="B99")
for (i in 2:3){co[i]=addmargins(table(pud[u[i],]$agegroups))}
```

but the output panel reprents:

*for (i in 2:3){co[i]=addmargins(table(pud[u[i],]$agegroups))}*

> *Error in `[.data.frame`(pud, u[i], ) : object 'u' not found*

How can I adjust the codes?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `u` is not found because `u` has not been made...

Comment: I would recommend using `case_when` to encode your conditions in a new variable (column) in `pud`. Then `group_by` the new column and `tally`. An `iris` example:
`iris_condition <- iris %>% 
 mutate(category = case_when(Species == "setosa" & Petal.Length < 4.5 ~ "Small Setosa",
               Species == "versicolor" & Petal.Length < 4.5 ~ "Small versicolor",
               TRUE ~ "General category"))

iris_condition %>% 
 group_by(category) %>% 
 tally()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the frequencies, why not do it like this?

```
sum(pud$icd3>="A00"&pud$icd3<="A99"|
              pud$icd3>="B00"&pud$icd3<="B94"|
              pud$icd3=="B99")
```